# C++ template: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, implicit-conversion

I cannot understand why this program fails to compile both with g++ 7.3 or clang++ 5.0 using -std=c++14.

`A` can be initialized from a `const int` as shown. A const reference to `A` can also be create from a `const int` but call to `f(const A &)` with a `const int` fails. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

struct V {
  int i;
  template <class T>
  V(const T &t) : i{t} {}
};

struct A {
  int i;
  A(V v) : i{v.i} {}
};

void f(const A &) {}

int main() {
  const auto i = 42;
  const A a1{i};              // OK
  std::cout << a1.i << '\n';  // 42
  const A &a2 = A{i};         // OK
  std::cout << a2.i << '\n';  // 42
  f(i);                       // no matching function for call to 'f'
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `f(i);`, [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is applied. And `i` (with type `const int`) needs to be converted to `A`, two user-defined conversions are required; from `const int` to `V`, and from `V` to `A`. But only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one implicit conversion sequence.

Bot `const A a1{i};` and `const A &a2 = A{i};` are [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), only one implicit conversion from `i` (with type `const int`) to the argument of `A`'s constructor (i.e. `V`) is required, so they work fine.

Note the difference between copy initialization and direct initialization,

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

As a workaround, you can perform explicit conversion on `i` before passing it to `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting `i` to an `A` for the purpose of the function call will require two user defined conversions (`int -> V -> A`). The standard places a hard limit of a *single* user defined conversion on each implicit conversion sequence.

The same would happen if you were to try and bind `a2` to `i` "directly". So you need to do a functional style cast (`A{i}`) when giving an argument to `f` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need two consecutive implicit type conversion here however C++ can do single conversion implicitley for you. If you want to let the compiler to generate the correct typed code for you, use `template` for the function `f` like following.

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T & x) { std::cout << x << std::endl;}
```

The reason why you need two type conversion is because of having only one constructor which takes type `V` in the struct. If you want to get rid of two type conversion as a second solution, you can add another constructor which takes `int` as a parameter like following

```
struct A {
    int i;
    A(V v) : i{v.i} {}
    A(int theI) : i{theI} { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Two user defined conversions are not supported in copy initialization. Simple work around to the problem is to wrap i with A while passing to funtion `f` with `f(A(i))`